# How to pass parameters to PHP template rendered with 'include'?

Tags: php, templates, parameters, include

need your help with PHP templating. I'm new to PHP (I'm coming from Perl+Embperl). Anyway, my problem is simple:

- I have a small template to render some item, let it be a blog post.
- The only way i know to use this template is to use 'include' directive.
- I want to call this template inside a loop going thru all the relevant blog posts.
- **Problem:** I need to pass a parameter(s) to this template; in this case reference to array representing a blog post.

Code looks something like this:

```
$rows = execute("select * from blogs where date='$date' order by date DESC");
foreach ($rows as $row){
  print render("/templates/blog_entry.php", $row);
}

function render($template, $param){
   ob_start();
   include($template);//How to pass $param to it? It needs that $row to render blog entry!
   $ret = ob_get_contents();
   ob_end_clean();
   return $ret;
}
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this? I'm really stumped :) Is there any other way to render a template?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Consider including a PHP file as if you were copy-pasting the code from the include into the position where the include-statement stands. This means that you inherit the current *scope*.

So, in your case, $param is already available in the given template.

Comment: For added differentness, try returning a value (`return 42;`) from your include and capturing that value: `$result = include 'filethatreturns42.php';` ;)

Comment: also there is a problem with this is that if you want to call a function which is visible on the template loader, you have to require it again in the template otherwise it fires an error

Answer (score 25):

$param should be already available inside the template. When you include() a file it should have the same scope as where it was included.

from http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

> When a file is included, the code it
>   contains inherits the variable scope
>   of the line on which the include
>   occurs. Any variables available at
>   that line in the calling file will be
>   available within the called file, from
>   that point forward. However, all
>   functions and classes defined in the
>   included file have the global scope.

You could also do something like:

```
print render("/templates/blog_entry.php", array('row'=>$row));

function render($template, $param){
   ob_start();
   //extract everything in param into the current scope
   extract($param, EXTR_SKIP);
   include($template);
   //etc.
```

Then $row would be available, but still called $row.

Comment: Very nice, thanks! Yes, i prefer to use hashes as params so that function is easily modifiable in the future.

Comment: This is how frameworks like CodeIgniter work. You load a template file and pass an array of values to it that get extracted and used in the template.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following helper functions when I work on simple websites:

```
function function_get_output($fn)
{
  $args = func_get_args();unset($args[0]);
  ob_start();
  call_user_func_array($fn, $args);
  $output = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  return $output;
}

function display($template, $params = array())
{
  extract($params);
  include $template;
}

function render($template, $params = array())
{
  return function_get_output('display', $template, $params);
}
```

display will output the template to the screen directly. render will return it as a string. It makes use of ob_get_contents to return the printed output of a function.