# php: include with URL parameter

Tags: php, include

I'm trying to include `db.php` and pass a variable to it.

This is what I have:

```
include "https://imprss.herokuapp.com/db.php?id=6626068";
```

Looks perfect to me but it simply won't work.

Comment: Have we tried enabling `error_reporting` yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a protocol such as `https` in your include directive, you should make sure that `allow_url_fopen` is enabled in your `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 0):

`https://imprss.herokuapp.com/db.php?id=6626068` is not returning PHP code, it outputs HTML code to be interpreted by the browser, if you are interested in getting the HTML code of that page then dont use `include()` instead you should use [cURL functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.curl.php) or the [fopen url handlers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.remote-files.php) .

Answer (score 0):

I would use a relative path, but only thing you are missing are braces around the quotes which define url.

Comment: Do braces mean parenthesis around the include call ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to include a php file on another server, because this would be a security vulnerability. You can, however, use file_get_contents to get the output of a php file.

Comment: Isn't is? Strange that the documentation says it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's asked before and answered. just go to link bottom:

[How to pass parameters with `include`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6805963/how-to-pass-parameters-with-include)