# How to use HD-WALLET-DERIVE in .php file?

Tags: php, ubuntu

I want to use commands from the [hd-wallet-derive command tool](https://github.com/dan-da/hd-wallet-derive) in my website.

For example I run this in Ubuntu terminal and it works fine:

```
$ ./hd-wallet-derive.php -g --key=xprv9tyUQV64JT5qs3RSTJkXCWKMyUgoQp7F3hA1xzG6ZGu6u6Q9VMNjGr67Lctvy5P8oyaYAL9CAWrUE9i6GoNMKUga5biW6Hx4tws2six3b9c --path=m/1 --cols=all --includeroot --numderive=3
```

But how can I use this code in my PHP file and get output?

For example if I click on a button in my PHP page, the below command run?

Comment: please specify what *works fine* means. Does this include providing some output, or you need to just run those commands?

Comment: When I use the command that I wrote upper in ubuntu terminal, It's gives me output. so how can I receive same output in .php file? how can I use -g in .php file and get the output?

Comment: You can use the `exec` function to run the terminal command from your php code. 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Links in the comments to https://stackoverflow.com/q/6805963/3995261 may be helpful (the short answer seems to be – it's not possible via `include`). The script you linked uses `getopt` so one question essentially is – how can you pass options to the script that uses `getopt`. May be the approach Valerian has suggested is the only option

Comment: thank u guys, when I create a .php file and copy this code in it '<?php

echo exec('whoami'); ' it's give me output in mozila. but when I use for example './hd-wallet-derive -g ' it dose not show any result? it require root acces? u give it root access? or any idea to excute this command in .php?

Answer (score 0):

hd-wallet-derive is sending usage info to stderr, not stdout.  To capture that, you could run the command as eg: ./hd-wallet-derive -g 2>&1

More to your question though, there is an option --outfile= to write report output to a given file.  In a web app, you should specify a unique filename for the user.  Further, you can specify what type of report output you want using the --format flag.

Usage info is here:
https://github.com/dan-da/hd-wallet-derive#usage

Comment: how can I use this library to get a PHP response like an array. I want to use this as a standard PHP library. Can you guide us on how we can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The code which you searched --format=jsonpretty and --outfile="logs/shell_result.txt"

```
    $cmd = 'php hd2/hd-wallet-derive.php --mnemonic="edge defense waste choose enrich upon flee junk siren film clown finish luggage leader kid quick brick print evidence swap drill paddle truly occur" ';
    $cmd.= '-g --path=m/44/60/0 --cols=all --includeroot --numderive=3 ';
    $cmd.= '--format=jsonpretty ';
    $cmd.= '--outfile="logs/shell_result.txt"';

    shell_exec($cmd);
    print_r(json_decode(file_get_contents('logs/shell_result.txt'), true));
```